# Creating a Class and calling on it's properties (javascript)

Tags: javascript, class, object

So the idea is to create a class Animal and the set properties to it as a new object

Here is what I have:

```
var name;
var type;
function Animal(name,type){
  this.type = type,
  this.name = name,
  toString = function(){return this.name + "is a " + this.type;}
};

var cat = new Animal('Max','cat');
cat.type;
```

everytime I run it - I seem to fail at the toString part? Pretty new and trying to learn this - is there something I am missing?

Comment: You don't need to declare those top variables, the arguments should be local to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare those top variables, the arguments should be local to the function. The syntax is wrong too, you should use semicolons, not commas, and `toString` becomes a global variable since you forgot to use `var`.

What you want is `this.toString` so `this` works inside and refers to the instance, or better yet, create a method on the `prototype` so it's re-usable for all instances of `Animal`:

```
function Animal(name,type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.name + "is a " + this.type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Animal(name, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.name = name;
};

Animal.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.name + "is a " + this.type;
}

var cat = new Animal('Max', 'cat');
console.log(cat); // Prints "Max is a cat"
```